# How do I fix a null pointer exception when adding to an array list?

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to add to an array list using a passed in object, but I keep getting a nullpointer exception when executing the line "order.add(shape)" below.

```
public void addSquare(Square shape) {
    System.out.println(shape.toString()); 
    order.add(shape);
}
```

How do I fix the exception? Do I need to initiate shape somewhere?

Comment: what is that "order." have you created that object?

Comment: order is the ArrayList<Square> I created that I am trying to add to  @Arvindsinc2

Comment: the stack trace from the NullPointerException might shed some light, but it pretty much has to be that order is null.

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek so how do I make it not null?

Comment: where do you intantiate and initialize this "order" object in your code?

Comment: in another method:   public TileManager() {
                                      ArrayList<Tile> order = new ArrayList<Tile>();
                       }  @mhasan

Comment: there is your mistake...you are creating order locally inside TileManager()